# Ansible regex to extract path from a list of strings excluding softlink notation

Tags: regex, ansible

I have to extract paths from a list of strings excluding the softlink maps.
Example list:

```
list1:
  - 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 usr grp   18 Nov 21 19:53 /path/dummy_link -> /some/file'
  - '-rw-r--r-- 1 usr grp    0 Nov 21 17:50 /path/file1.txt'
  - 'drwxr-xr-x 1 usr grp 4096 Nov 21 17:51 /path/dir1'
```

I am trying with `map` and `regex_replace` as below:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ list1 | map('regex_replace',regxp,bckref) | list }}"
  vars:
    regxp: '^.+(/path/.+)(.*?)$'
    bckref: '\1'
```

and the result I am getting is:

```
"msg": [
    "/path/dummy_link -> /some/file",
    "/path/file1.txt",
    "/path/dir1"
]
```

The expected output is:

```
"msg": [
    "/path/dummy_link",
    "/path/file1.txt",
    "/path/dir1"
]
```

What could be the `regex` to get rid of the substring   `-> /some/file` which will not be present in all the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
{{ list1 | map('regex_replace','^.+(/path/\\S+).*','\\1') | list }}
```

Or, with `regex_search`:

```
{{ list1 | map('regex_search','/path/\\S+') | list }}
```

The `^.+(/path/\S+).*` regex matches

- `^` -  start of string
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(/path/\S+)` - Group 1: `/path/` + one or more non-whitespace chars
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The `\1` replaces with the Group 1 value.

Comment: Thanks! I have replaced ```\S``` with ```\\S```

Comment: Ansible was throwing some json error without the ```\\S``` That's why I've replaced. Thanks so much @Wiktor